# Logging God process to STDOUT instead of a file

Tags: ruby-on-rails, logging, stdout, resque, god

I have a rails application that uses Redis, Resque worker and scheduler. I'm using God to monitor both the worker and the scheduler. That part is working.

What I need to know is if there's a way to output Resque worker and scheduler logs to STDOUT instead of a file. I know God allows to log any process its watching to a file, using `w.log = file/path`.

Running God with `god -c config/resque.god -D` outputs God's logs. Is there a way to output God's process to this stream? So Resque worker, scheduler and God outputs go to the same stream.

Answer (score 0):

You can take a look at `w.log_cmd` to output the log stream to STDOUT.